# java list shift items by rearranging links

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm working with a linked list in java and I need to take a list of x objects and move the odd positioned objects to the end of the list.

I have to do it by using linking, no new nodes, no list.data exchanges.

I feel like I have a decent handle when I'm moving stuff from one list to another, but traversing and appending with references to only one list is really tough.

Here's the actual question ---

Write a method shift that rearranges the elements of a list of integers by moving to the end of the list all values that are in odd-numbered positions and otherwise preserving list order. For example, suppose a variable list stores the following values:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
The call of list.shift(); should rearrange the list to be:

[0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
you must solve this problem by rearranging the links of the list.

---

below is the class that I need to write the method before (with the aforementioned restrictions.

I can't really come up with a plan of attack.

```
// A LinkedIntList object can be used to store a list of integers.
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;   // node holding first value in list (null if empty)
    private String name = "front";   // string to print for front of list

    // Constructs an empty list.
    public LinkedIntList() {
        front = null;
    }

    // Constructs a list containing the given elements.
    // For quick initialization via Practice-It test cases.
    public LinkedIntList(int... elements) {
        this("front", elements);
    }

    public LinkedIntList(String name, int... elements) {
        this.name = name;
        if (elements.length > 0) {
            front = new ListNode(elements[0]);
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
                current.next = new ListNode(elements[i]);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    // Constructs a list containing the given front node.
    // For quick initialization via Practice-It ListNode test cases.
    private LinkedIntList(String name, ListNode front) {
        this.name  = name;
        this.front = front;
    }

    // Appends the given value to the end of the list.
    public void add(int value) {
        if (front == null) {
            front = new ListNode(value, front);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            } 
            current.next = new ListNode(value);
        }
    }

    // Inserts the given value at the given index in the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index <= size
    public void add(int index, int value) {
        if (index == 0) {
            front = new ListNode(value, front);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            } 
            current.next = new ListNode(value, current.next);
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof LinkedIntList) {
            LinkedIntList other = (LinkedIntList) o;
            return toString().equals(other.toString());   // hackish
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Returns the integer at the given index in the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index < size
    public int get(int index) {
        ListNode current = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current.data;
    }

    // Removes the value at the given index from the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index < size
    public void remove(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            front = front.next;
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of elements in the list.
    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode current = front;
        while (current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    // Returns a text representation of the list, giving
    // indications as to the nodes and link structure of the list.
    // Detects student bugs where the student has inserted a cycle
    // into the list.
    public String toFormattedString() {
        ListNode.clearCycleData();

        String result = this.name;

        ListNode current = front;
        boolean cycle = false;
        while (current != null) {
            result += " -> [" + current.data + "]";
            if (current.cycle) {
                result += " (cycle!)";
                cycle = true;
                break;
            }
            current = current.__gotoNext();
        }

        if (!cycle) {
            result += " /";
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a text representation of the list.
    public String toString() {
        return toFormattedString();
    }

    // Returns a shorter, more "java.util.LinkedList"-like text representation of the list.
    public String toStringShort() {
        ListNode.clearCycleData();

        String result = "[";

        ListNode current = front;
        boolean cycle = false;
        while (current != null) {
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                result += ", ";
            }
            result += current.data;
            if (current.cycle) {
                result += " (cycle!)";
                cycle = true;
                break;
            }
            current = current.__gotoNext();
        }

        if (!cycle) {
            result += "]";
        }

        return result;
    }


    // ListNode is a class for storing a single node of a linked list.  This
    // node class is for a list of integer values.
    // Most of the icky code is related to the task of figuring out
    // if the student has accidentally created a cycle by pointing a later part of the list back to an earlier part.

    public static class ListNode {
        private static final List<ListNode> ALL_NODES = new ArrayList<ListNode>();

        public static void clearCycleData() {
            for (ListNode node : ALL_NODES) {
                node.visited = false;
                node.cycle = false;
            }
        }

        public int data;          // data stored in this node
        public ListNode next;     // link to next node in the list
        public boolean visited;   // has this node been seen yet?
        public boolean cycle;     // is there a cycle at this node?

        // post: constructs a node with data 0 and null link
        public ListNode() {
            this(0, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and null link
        public ListNode(int data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and given link
        public ListNode(int data, ListNode next) {
            ALL_NODES.add(this);
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.visited = false;
            this.cycle = false;
        }

        public ListNode __gotoNext() {
            return __gotoNext(true);
        }

        public ListNode __gotoNext(boolean checkForCycle) {
            if (checkForCycle) {
                visited = true;

                if (next != null) {
                    if (next.visited) {
                        // throw new IllegalStateException("cycle detected in list");
                        next.cycle = true;
                    }
                    next.visited = true;
                }
            }
            return next;
        }
    }

// YOUR CODE GOES HERE

}
```

Comment: Drawing such structures on paper is usually a good preparation step to start the attack...

Comment: Maybe start with creating the two lists `0 2 4 6` and `1 3 5 7` from your source list first, then link them at the end.

Comment: I assume this is `[homework]`?

Comment: One of the big constrains is that I can't create new nodes. The core issue I'm struggling with is how to rearrange links in a list. I keep wondering if I could write a small helper method to move a node from one index to another.

Comment: Also, this is a practice site provided by my java textbook, but it's not homework assigned by my class. I try to work through all of these before I get into the homework and quizzes :)

Comment: ListNode n = otherListNode; is not creating new nodes.  After the statement n and otherListNode point to the same data.

Comment: A great way to code, and this is a preferred commercial technique, is to write your unit tests *before* writing any code. It's called "TDD" - [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). It can really help here because it makes you formally think about the behaviour you're seeking, and you'll immediately know when your implementation works because your tests will pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see it this way:

first we need some sort of cursor that will go through the list and point to our "current" node

second we need some boolean variable (i'll call it INV) initialized as FALSE ... everytime we move a node in the list, we invert INV

if you go through the list from the left, the second element is the first to be rearanged, so that will be our initial cursor position

lets take a reference on that element/node, and keep that reference as abort criteria

start of loop:

now remove the current node from the list and insert it at the end of the list (move to the end ... not that the cursor may not move with the node ...)

move the cursor to the node that is right of the former position of the node we just moved (if that exists)

if the current element is our abort criteria (first element we moved) we can assume the list is sorted now in the desired order -> we are finished -> exit the loop ... if it's not our abort criteria ... go on

evaluate "index of the cursor is even" to either TRUE or FALSE ... XOR that with INV

if the result is TRUE move the cursor to the next element ... if it's FALSE remove the node and insert it at the end (move it to the end)

do the loop

--

this approach will not preserve the order while we move through the list, but will have the list in the desired order when it finishes ...

the INV var is for compensation the index shifts when removing a node ... (0,1,2,3 ... if you remove the 1 and put it at the end, 2 will have an odd index, so if we invert that with every move, we get the "right" elements)